# How to access a new browser tab

Tags: ruby, watir

Watir noob here. I'm attempting to connect to and manipulate a newly spawned browser tab, but am a little confused about how to recognize the new tab. Here's what I have:

Windows 7 (32 bit) IE 10

Ruby 1.9.3-p392/TDM-32.4.5.2

LOCAL GEMS

watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32)

watir-classic (3.6.0)

watir-webdriver (0.6.3)

Basic gist of the Script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'Watir'
ie=Watir::Browser.new
```

... First part of the script on the original browser tab is completed. The original browser tab generates a second browser tab, which I need to access.
I've read a response somewhere that I need to link to the browser tab prior to attaching to it, but I'm having a hard time recognizing the link by the href, url or title: (where 'path...' = http url)

```
ie.link(:href, "path...").click
```

--Uncaught exception: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"], :href=>"path..."

```
ie.link(:url, "path...").click
```

--Uncaught exception: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"], :url=>"path..."

```
ie.a(:href, "path...").click
```

--Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"], :url=>"path..."}

However, if I try the following:

```
ie2 = Watir::IE.attach(:title, 'New_Tab_Title')
```

--"Unable to locate a window with title of New_Tab_Title"

Firstly, how do I point to the new url or browser tab?  If I do a ie.close after the second tab opens, the first tab closes, so clearly I don't recognize this new tab (even if it appears to have focus).

Secondly, am I correct in assuming that I need to connect to the link/url first, then attach to the browser tab, then I can continue with populating fields?

Lastly, is there a short name url I can use, as the url generated is very long, or do we need to insert the entire url?

Answer (score 8):

#### I would recommend using watir-webdriver on tab handling:

#### Try the following

```
MEDBEDbs-iMac:~ medbedb$ irb
1.9.3p392 :001 > require 'watir-webdriver'
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x..f87e94a30e87e1e60 url="about:blank" title="about:blank"> 
1.9.3p392 :003 > b.goto "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp"
 => "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp" 
1.9.3p392 :004 > b.title
 => "HTML Links"
```

#### Here a new window is opened in a new tab.

```
1.9.3p392 :005 > b.a(:text, 'HTML links').click
 => [] 
1.9.3p392 :006 > b.windows.count
 => 2
```

#### But watir-webdriving is still handling the previous page..

```
1.9.3p392 :007 > b.title
 => "HTML Links"
```

#### Switching to recently opened tab.

```
1.9.3p392 :008 > b.windows.last.use
 => #<Watir::Window:0x..fd949289f2b083062 located=true> 
1.9.3p392 :009 > b.title
 => "Tryit Editor v1.7"
```

#### From here you can do whatever you need in a new tab.

```
1.9.3p392 :010 > b.windows.last.close
 => #<Watir::Window:0x..fd949289f2b083062 located=true>
```

#### After closing the new tab watir will switch back to initial tab.

```
1.9.3p392 :011 > b.title
 => "HTML Links" 
1.9.3p392 :012 > b.close
 => true
```

Show us the code or url to the web-pate to get more detailed results...

Comment: The watir-classic and watir-webdriver api should be the same (ie you should not need to specifically be using watir-webdriver).

Comment: I have had some tab switching functionality issues with classic watir in in the past, so chose to use watir-webdriver..

Comment: Thanks for the advice Sveatoslav, but after I require watir-webdriver, the ie10 tabs are opening as new windows and I've seemed to have lost the ability to navigate in the pages with the script I have (just requiring watir-webdriver). Using strictly what you posted, I don't get a new tab with b.a(:text, 'HTML links').click, but the window goes to the link. Maybe an ie10 issue or something. @Justin Ko - are you able to select the new tab using watir-classic in ie10? If so, what are you doing?

Comment: @user2320514, the above code works fine for me in watir-classic using IE8. Unfortunately, I do not have IE10.

Comment: @Justin Ko - I've gone to ie 9 and the html links still opens in a new window, not tab. If I perform the same steps manually, I get the new window in a tab. So something is up with how Watir is opening the tab as a separate window. Do I have a conflict somewhere? b = Watir::Browser.new :ie opens http://localhost:5557/

Comment: My understanding is that opening new tabs vs windows is based on the IE settings. It is not controlled by Watir. Regardless of whether or not it is a new window vs a new tab, the code should still work.

Comment: ... or for some reason is Watir treating any links as a new window. This may be only a problem for me on this computer, so I may have to try another computer to test.

Comment: make sure all the pages are in the same security group (e.g. trusted)

Comment: @Chuck van der Linden - I've Enabled Protected Mode selected on all the security zones in IE (which will throw an error if not) and have them all set to medium. I've been looking into a possible gem conflict, but it really sounds like in IE issue. It's strange that I can open the spawned window manually, but not able to get Watir to recognize it, especially with the responses. Must be something I've done! I'm going to install on other machines and try, as testing with webdriver in IE didn't make a difference. I can't use any other browsers for our app. I'll post a follow-up.

Comment: Did you doublecheck the IE setting that opens new links as tabs vs in a new window?

Comment: Yes, I've verified that a new link will open as a tab, not window. Again, it's strange that I can step through the steps manually in irb and the link will open as a tab, but running the ruby script (automated) will open it as a new window. Is there any way to pay a company to help with ruby/watir issues? I would think there would be some type of help for companies that are trying to get up and running.