# Watir WebDriver browser object loses current window upon opening new tab (FIREFOX)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to test clicking on multiple links on the same page, but then be able to switch active tabs. However once I click on a link with target=_blank or if I open a new tab on purpose, it routes me to a new tab and I can't get back to the old tab.

**Note: I am using Firefox for testing. Chrome does appear to work properly and provides a window count of 2**

Here is a simple IRB snippet to show what I mean:

```
2.2.1 :001 > require 'watir-webdriver'
 => true
2.2.1 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => 'default'
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x..fa8c7116334ddce82 url="about:blank" title="">
2.2.1 :003 > b.goto 'amazon.com'
 => "http://amazon.com"
2.2.1 :004 > b.a(:class => 'nav-logo-link').click(:command, :shift)
 => nil
2.2.1 :005 > b.windows.count
 => 1
```

I see two tabs opened, which the `(:command, :shift)` option is meant to do.. but how do I go back to the first one if the browser object only has 1 window?

It just seems that I can't find anyone having the same problem so perhaps its a firefox issue or my environment maybe?

Running on Mac OSX, FF version 44, Ruby 2.2.1, watir-webdriver 0.9.1

Comment: Unless you are being paid by Amazon to test their site, you should not be doing any browser automation targeted at their site as it is a violation of their conditions of use.  Specifically `This license does not include... ...any derivative use of any Amazon Service or its contents; any downloading, copying, or other use of account information for the benefit of any third party; or any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools. ` -- ANY browser automation tool, fits the 'robots or similar' clause.

Comment: ...I just used Amazon as a simple example since the website I'm testing I'm doing on isn't live yet. Guess I'll have to pick a different site to give an example with for future reference lol

Comment: I don't quite get what are you asking here, but worth to check my answer for windows handling here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222446/how-to-access-a-new-browser-tab/16223773#16223773

Comment: I clarified the question and did discover that Chrome does, upon click, keep all windows in the browser object. @SveatoslavCircel Thanks for posting that article since it is basically my question, why doesn't your answer of switching tabs work for me in firefox?

Comment: No idea, as a workaround, you could instantiate another browser instance, do stuff there, then close it and move back to initial instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "amazon.com"
link = b.a(:class => 'nav-logo-link')
b.execute_script("return arguments[0].target = '_blank'", link)
link.click
puts b.windows.count
```

Main idea is not to try to use a link in a special way to get two windows but modify the link to get two windows in a natural way.

Comment: That does appear to solve part of the issue, and I like the workaround. Still curious to know if this is a known bug for the firefox driver or not. Also, it seems that the firefox config for browser.link.open_newwindow is defaulting to 2 for this driver, Which still treats target='_blank' as a new window instead of tab. You know how to change this for testing? Not a huge deal but the tests looks alot cleaner when viewed with tabs instead of a bunch of windows going up and down

Comment: Well. I used method above previously but not now. The secret is I never use browser windows\tabs. When it is necessary to open a bunch of links I am storing hrefs to an array to open it one by one. So I have no ideas how to do it more clear.